I tried to download Prophet package but got error message -'installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit' status
I failed to install Prophet package in R. A lot of error messages appeared. All of them have 'installation of package had non-zero exit' phrase. This appears for many packages such as 'lifecycle', 'loo' etc.
Can you help me resolve the issue?
I expect a solution to this failed installation problem of prophet package on R.

Hello Subhajit. Please properly format the text above so that the error messages are distinct by enclosing them in  
